# Returning and reusing multiple variables in python

Tags: python, variables, return-value

I have written a program opening and reading informations from a file, saving them in different variables, so they are easier to re-use after. I make it return them after, a bit like

> return (Xcoord,Ycoord,Xrotation,Yrotation)

I after want to use them in another program, so I've tried calling the first one (let it be "prog1"), and then using them, like this:

> def prog2():
>
> ```
> prog1()
>
> Xcoord.append(1)
> ```

I get a variable error, as I reference X before assignment. I've seen that I have to create a variable for my results, like x=prog1(), but what if I want to have several variables returned AND reused after?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really hard to parse, in part because you're using wrong terminology (functions are not programs). But I think you're asking about returning tuples from a function. That's doable:

```
def prog1():
  return (Xcoord,Ycoord,Xrotation,Yrotation)

def prog2():
  Xcoord, Ycoord, Xrotation, Yrotation = prog1()
  # do stuff with variables
```

Answer (score 1):

when you return multiple variables from a function it is actually returning a tuple so:

```
def func1():
    return x, y, z

x,y,z = func1()
```

thats it

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns some variables, but you're not using them anywhere.

When you write a function like this:

```
def square(number):
    return number**2
```

You then call it like this:

```
squared=square(6)
```

Then `squared` will be equal to `36`.

---

You should do exactly the same here:

```
Xc, Yc, Xrot, Yrot = prog1()

# use the returned variables
Xc.append(1)
```